# MVC4 WebApi Knockout JSON Invalid operand to 'in'

Tags: json, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, runtime-error

Hy, I'm stuck with this error message and I can not find an solution.

I get this message error in the Knockout JavaScript library v2.2.0:

> Unhandled exception at line 1053, column 5 in
>   localhost:port/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.debug.js 0x800a138f -
>   Microsoft JScript runtime error: Invalid operand to 'in': Object
>   expected If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be
>   safely continued.

It stops at this line of code in knockout-2.2.0.debug.js

```
 if ((initialValues !== null) && (initialValues !== undefined) && !('length' in initialValues))
```

I use this WebApi:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
  IEnumerable<Product> products = new List<Product>() 
    { 
        new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato_Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 }, 
        new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M }, 
        new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M } 
    };

      public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts(){
            return products.AsEnumerable();    }
```

The scripts that I use are in a header section

```
@section Testscripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.debug.js"></script> 


}
```

And the Knockout code in the footer default script section

```
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">      
        var apiUrl = '@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { httproute = "", controller = "products" })';  

        function Product(data) {            
            this.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
            this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
            this.Price = ko.observableArray(data.Price);
            this.Category = ko.observable(data.Category);

        }

        function ProductViewModel() {

            var self = this;
            self.myproducts = ko.observableArray([]);


        $.getJSON(apiUrl, function (allData) {
            var mappedProducts = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new Product(item) });

            self.myproducts(mappedProducts);

        });
      };
   ko.applyBindings(new ProductViewModel);
}
```

and show the data in body:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: myproducts">
    <li>
        <input data-bind="value: Id" />
        <input data-bind="value: Name" />
        <input data-bind="value: Category" />
        <input data-bind="value: Price" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is in your `Product` function.

You want to create an `ko.observableArray` from `data.Price` which is a decimal value and not an array of values, which results in this not so nice exception.

Change to `ko.observable` and it should work:

```
function Product(data) {            
        this.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
        this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
        this.Price = ko.observable(data.Price);
        this.Category = ko.observable(data.Category);

    }
```

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. Thnx